# PreventDefault SweetAlert2

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert, sweetalert2

I got this function that override my native js alerts:

```
function alert(message, title = 'Test', type = 'info')
{
    // event.preventDefault();
    if(typeof(swal) != 'undefined') {
        swal({
            html: message,
            title: title,
            type: type,
            width: '24rem',
        }).then((result) => {
            return result.value;
        });
    }
    else {
        alert(message);
    }
}
```

At the end of my PHP functions, i have an alert('success'), and then i redirect to another page. With the native JS alert, it waits me to click the OK button to continue. Now with this swal function, it shows the alert and redirects immediatly. Is there a way to avoid this behavior and act like the native alert, without changing the function signature?

Comment: it is a js window.location.href

Answer (score 0):

The difference is that the `alert()` is modal. This means it blocks all other input and output until it's dismissed. The Sweetalert is not.

You can make it behave in a similar manner by using a callback function which you execute when the OK button is clicked in the Sweetalert. You can do that by passing the function to `alert()`, then calling it in the `then()` block, like this:

```
function alert(message, title = 'Test', type = 'info', callback) {
  if (typeof(swal) != 'undefined') {
    swal({
      html: message,
      title: title,
      type: type,
      width: '24rem',
    }).then(() => {
      callback && callback();
    });
  } else {
    alert(message);
    callback && callback();            
  }
}

// example usage:
alert('foo bar', 'title', 'info', function() {
  window.location.assign('somewhere_else.php');
});
```

Comment: ok, but in this case i would have to change all my alerts to pass this callback. I am trying to avoid this because i have too many alerts to change.

Comment: In which case it's not really possible to do what you require.